# What's the meaning of "懐けばとことん懐きます"

Tags: meaning

The entire sentence is **たまに人見知り、気まぐれで人懐っこくなります、懐けばとことん懐きます。**

It was written on the profile of my friend who's from Osaka. And I think there maybe some slang in this sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

とことん is Osaka/Kyoto dialect and means 徹底的{てっていてき}に, thoroughly/completely.

I'd translate the sentence as:

Sometimes I'm shy, but then I can suddenly become social; (then) if I become attached to someone I become completely attached.

EDIT:
The dictionary I looked up とことん in flagged it as dialectal with this usage, but looking in other sources shows it as Standard Japanese.

Comment: 「とことん」は標準語だと思います